# Apache Kafka Multiple Consumer Instances

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a consumer that is supposed to read messages from a topic. This consumer actually reads the messages and writes them to a time series database. We have multiple instances of the time series database running as a cluster on multiple physical machines.

Our plan is to deploy the consumer on all those machines where the time series service is running. So if I have 5 nodes on which the time series service is running, I will install one consumer instance per node. All those consumer instances belong to the same consumer group. So in pictures the set up looks like below:

[image]

As you can see, the Producer P1 and P2 write into 2 partitions namely partition 1 and partition 2 of the kafka topic. I then have 4 instances of the time series service where one consumer is running per instance. How should I read using my consumer properly such that I do not end up with duplicate messages in my time series database?

Edit: After reading through the Kafka documentation, I came across these two statements:

```
If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then this works just like a traditional queue balancing load over the consumers.

If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then this works like publish-subscribe and all messages are broadcast to all consumers.
```

So in my case above, it is behaving like a Queue? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all consumers belong to the same consumer group (have the same `group.id` configuration property), then the Kafka topic will behave for you like a queue.

Important:  there is no reason to have more consumer group instances in your consumer group than partitions, since one partition can only be assigned to a single instance of a consumer group. If you have more consumer instances (with the same group id) than partitions, some of the consumer instances will be idle.

[image: http://kafka.apache.org/images/consumer-groups.png]

Comment: "kafka topic will behave like a queue" is not quite correct, since ordering is guaranteed for queues, but not for Kafka topics. Ordering is only guaranteed on the partition level.